# Different profile page for different users using PHP

Tags: php

Hey I'm new to php need help creating anew page per user. I have a user login and registration system already. I also have a profiles.php page but, how can I let the website make an automatic webpage for every new user.

Whenever I try to connect it through `$_GET` or `$_POST` I get an Undefined index error.

```php
include ("includes/profiles.dbh.inc.php");

$requested_user = $_POST['mailuid'];

try{
    $stmt2 = $conn2->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id = ?");

    $stmt2->execute(array($requested_user));

    $mydata = $stmt2->fetch();               
} catch (Exception $e) {               
    //error with mysql
    die();
}
```

Comment: automatic webpage? how, please give an example

Comment: Change `$_POST` to `$_GET` and then access your application with the query string containing `mailuid`. Ex. `localhost/index.php?mailuid=1`

Comment: Also, turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question come up a few times. One of the first things you need to consider is *how is the user going to interact* with this page.

1. Are they going to access it via links? http://example.com/index.php?user=1
2. Or are they going to submit a form via *post*? http://example.com/index.php

This distinction is important because it changes the way you handle their request.

Let's look at each one:

1. Via a link: http://example.com/index.php?user=1

This will issue a *get* request to your server so you need to handle it via `$_GET`.

```
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
   $userId = $_GET['user'];

   // ... query your DB and output result
}
```

2. Via a form using *post*: http://example.com/index.php (body with contain "user=1").

This will issue a *post* request to your server so you need to handle it via `$_POST`

```
if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
   $userId = $_POST['user'];

   // ... query your DB and output result
}
```

On a side note, it is important to know that an HTML `<form>` can submit either a *post* or *get* request. You can control this via it's *method* attribute. If you don't specify the method attribute, then it defaults to *get*.

```
<form method="post">
   ...
</form>

<form method="get">
   ...
</form>
```

So, to answer your question. You're likely getting an undefined error because you're trying to access the post array using the key *mailuid* (`$_POST['mailuid']`) but that does not exist. It doesn't exist because:

- you're receiving a get request and the post is empty OR
- you are receiving a post request but it doesn't contain the key *mailuid*

**To debug, go back to the basics - use `$_GET`**

Change your code to use `$_GET['mailuid']` and then make sure you access your page with the corresponding query string - `...?mailuid=1`.

Finally, turn on error reporting - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/296555. You should always do this and correct all errors and warnings.